# Outlook 2016 folder permission error message

Tags: exchange-2016

User A has given user B full permission access to a folder in their inbox (user A's inbox).  User B has added user A's email account in Account settings.
When user B selects the folder name in their inbox (user B's inbox) a message is displayed:
'The set of folders cannot be opened. Network problems are preventing connection to Microsoft Exchange.'
User B also have access to another folder from user C's inbox.  This folder can not be opened even though it was available before adding user A's email details in Account Settings.

Answer (score 0):

> **When user B selects the folder name in their inbox (user B's inbox) a message is displayed**

Is that the folder of **user B** couldn't be opened, or the one of **user A** couldn't?

How did you add the User A in **Account Settings**? Adding an account(**New...**) or an additional mailbox(**Open these additional mailboxes**):
[image]
[image]